# Missing Artboards in an Adobe Illustrator file

Tags: graphics, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I had saved an Illustrator file (.ai) to an external storage device as backup. I copied the file back to my PC and now when I open it, I do not see any of my previous artboards. However, the file size of my .ai file is the same.

Under the artboards panel, it only shows one plain artboard. But the actual file had 13 artbooards.
I have checked if the artboards were hidden but they weren't.

Please help me restore my artboards

OS: Windows 10 Pro